# How to create table with booktabs package?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I would like to create the following tables with the booktabs package but I am not quite sure how to do that

[image]

and

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No you do not. Booktabs is especially made to deter the use of vertical lines in tables. Also please show some code as else this question will probably be put on hold as a please do this for me` question.

Comment: Vertical rules are *not* recommended with booktabs, as they do not intersect booktabs rules, due to the vertical padding around the latter.

Comment: If you read booktabs documentation, you will find that booktabs does not support vertical rules. Unless you redefine the rules commands, you will see white gaps between horizontal and vertical rules. If you need all this rules, you should look at `tabular` environment, and the `multicolumn` command together with the [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline)- and [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package. Or usethe package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/array), which relatively easily will product the requested tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**calstable and tabularx table**

Here are both of your tables typeset as `calstable`s, *i.e*. using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals). I have also typeset the first table using [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline), [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow). I used [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), because that package can calculate column width taking into consideration all the necessary variables.

**calstable**

`calstable` has no support for double rules (double borders), so I have faked such rules using narrow rows and columns.

Since I typeset both tables in the same document, I moved the table setup commands and the definition off shortcuts from the table preamble to the document preamble. I have tweaked all rules (lines), ensuring that no single rules are cutting double double rules. Therefore, you will see the shortcut `\lb`, `\rb` used several places, to switch off remove and switch on rules for individual cells. How the double vertical rules shall connect to double horizontal rules depends on local typographical traditions, so I do not guarantee that may choice is correct in your jurisdiction.

I filled in some cell content to typeset the table with correct row height, and as  consequence, I increase the row heights in the first table to *two* `\baselineskip`s, compared to previous example. In addition, I vertically centred the cell content in all cells by using a documented hook, see the command `\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}

% Set up the carlstable
\makeatletter
%% All rules of same weight
\def\cals@framers@width{0.3pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.3pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.3pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.3pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.3pt}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}            % All cell contents vertically centred

% Shorthands for spanning cells, table rules and the spece between columns and rows (padding)
\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right Border (rules) switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\tp{\ifdim\cals@paddingT=0.0pt\relax    % Top padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingT}{0pt}\fi}

\def\bp{\ifdim\cals@paddingB=0.0pt\relax    % Bottom padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingB}{0pt}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining 11 columns, 2 are for double vertical rules (col2 and col7)
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*3)}
                   {2pt}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*2)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*1)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*2)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*4)}
                   {2pt}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*2)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*1)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*2)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/21*4)}
            }

\makeatletter
% R1H1  % This first row is just to ‘fake’ double horizontal lines
\thead{%
\brow
    \rb\tp\cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\rb
    \cell{}\tp
    \ht\cals@current@row=2pt
\erow
%
%R2H2 % Header
\brow
    \alignC\cell{C}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{}
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R3B1
\brow
    \cell{C}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \ht\cals@current@row=2\normalbaselineskip
\erow
%R5B3
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{C}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R6B4
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \ht\cals@current@row=2\normalbaselineskip
\erow
%R7B5
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{C}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R8B6
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \ht\cals@current@row=2\normalbaselineskip
\erow
%R9B7
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{C}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R10B9  % This last row is just to ‘fake’ double horizontal lines
\brow
    \rb\bp\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\rb
    \cell{}\bp
    \ht\cals@current@row=2pt
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{calstable}[l]
% Defining 5 columns, 1 are for double vertical rules (col2)
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/15*3)}
                   {2pt}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/15*2)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/15*1)}
                   {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/15*3)}
            }

\makeatletter
% R1H1  % This first row is just to ‘fake’ double horizontal lines
\thead{%
\brow
    \rb\tp\cell{}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\rb\tp
    \ht\cals@current@row=2pt
\erow
%
%R2H2 % Header
\brow
    \alignC\cell{C}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R4B2
\brow
    \bb\cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R5B3
\brow
    \cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R6B4
\brow
    \cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R7B5
\brow
    \cell{C}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R8B6
\brow
    \bb\cell{C}\bb
    \cell{}
    \bb\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb
\erow
%R10B9  % This last row is just to ‘fake’ double horizontal lines
\brow
    \bb\rb\bp\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\rb
    \cell{}\bb
    \ht\cals@current@row=2pt
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

**tabularx and friends**

Here is your first table typeset with [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and friends. As you will see, the setup and definition of columns and column width are pretty complicated. To have correct connecting rules, I used the [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, multirow, hhline}

% Two shorthands to secured equal rowheigth 
\newcommand*{\hz}{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\rule{1cm}{1.5\normalbaselineskip}}}}
\newcommand*{\vz}{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\rule{1cm}{2.5\normalbaselineskip}}}}

% Define four new X column types based on width. tabularx takes care of the maths involved
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.4\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

% Uncomment to see margins etc.
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{.15pt}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt} % Push first line of text away from rules above.

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|B||C|D|C|A||C|D|C|A|}

\hhline{|*{9}{=}|}
\hz B   &    \multicolumn{4}{c||}{}   &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}\\
\hhline{|-||----||----|}
\hz B   &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}   &    &      &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &   & \\
\hhline{|-||--|-|-||--|-|-|}
\vz\multirow[c]{3}{=}{\centering B}     &       &      &    &      &    &   &   & \\
\hhline{|~||--|-|-||--|-|-|}
\hz     &    C  &      &    &      &    &   &   & \\
\hhline{|-||--|-|-||--|-|-|}
\vz\multirow[c]{3}{=}{B}    &       &     &    &      &    &   &   & \\
\hhline{|~||--|-|-||--|-|-|}
\hz     &    C  &      &   &      &    &   &   & \\
\hhline{|-||--|-|-||--|-|-|}
\vz \hz\multirow[c]{3}{=}{B}    &       &      &    &      &    &   &   & \\
\hhline{|~||--|-|-||--|-|-|}
\hz     &    C  &      &    &      &    &   &   &  \\
\hhline{|*{9}{=}|}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```